# Django: MP3 file being opened, not saved, on Apple devices

Tags: python, django, content-type

I am working with Python and Django 1.9.

I manage to serve an MP3 file for download and it works fine on my computer and on my Android phone. However, on my iPad, the file isn't downloaded and saved as a file; it is directly opened in both the Safari and Chrome browsers.

Is there any way to save the file on the iPad?

This is the code snippet that I'm using:

```
fsock = open(filename, 'r')
response = HttpResponse(fsock, content_type='audio/mpeg')
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s.mp3" % (filename)
return response
```

Is there something I should change in my code or is it rather a constraint from Apple's OS to avoid saving downloaded MP3 files directly from the browser?